Activating 3D acceleration in a virtual machine for Gazebo
I am running Gazebo ionic on a VirtualBox machine running Ubuntu 24 on a MS Windows 11 host.
When I activate 3D acceleration in the settings for that machine, the Gazebo sim viewer only show a black area where the 3D is supposed to be shown.

When the acceleration is disabled, the simulation does show some 3D, but very slow of course.
Any pointers on how to improve the graphics situation in Gazebo?
Thanks!

Gazebo works natively on Windows (see https://gazebosim.org/docs/latest/install_windows/). Have you tried that?

Hi @azeey, thanks for the tip, however I'm trying to set up a PX4 dev / demo environment on an Ubuntu virtual machine, that's why i'm not using Gazebo directly on Windows

You might have better luck running with the ogre render engine rather than ogre2 since the latter needs more features from the GPU. You'd do this by passing the --render-engine ogre command line flag. Example: gz sim -v4 shapes.sdf --render-engine ogre
